# Need to join 2 tables with more than 200K data. How to prepare the query?

Tags: mysql, join

I have to join 2 tables which are currently holding more than 200K data each. I have members and orders table. I would like to get members who didn't order anything.

I tried following SQL queries;

**Structure** (just listing what I need)

```
ORDERS                  MEMBERS
id                      id
member_id               fullName
                        email
                        landLine
                        cellPhone
```

**Query1**

```
$sql  = 'SELECT '.PREFIX.'members.fullName
           , '.PREFIX.'members.email
           , '.PREFIX.'members.landLine
           , '.PREFIX.'members.cellPhone, ';
$sql .= 'FROM '.PREFIX.'members';
$sql .= 'LEFT JOIN ';
$sql .= PREFIX.'orders';
$sql .= ' ON ';
$sql .= PREFIX.'members.id = '.PREFIX.'orders.member_id';
$sql .= ' WHERE '.PREFIX.'orders.member_id IS NULL LIMIT 50';
```

**Query 2**

```
$sql2  = 'select id, fullName, email, landLine, cellphone 
          from '.PREFIX.'members 
          where '.PREFIX.'members.id not in 
             (select member_id from '.PREFIX.'orders) 
          LIMIT 50';
```

**Query 3**

```
$sql3  = 'select id, fullName, email, landLine, cellphone 
          from '.PREFIX.'members m 
          where not exists 
            (select null from '.PREFIX.'orders o where s.members_id = o.id) 
          LIMIT 50';
```

All 3 queries so far didn't work. More than a minute passed, I am still waiting for the results.

What is the most elegant way to do this? Which one is faster and using less resources? I don't see anything wrong here why it would work but for some reason it just can't list.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What indexes are on your tables and what does EXPLAIN PLAN show?

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on `id` and `members_id`

Comment: And your aliases on query 3 are all wrong.

Comment: I thought everything was clear with my `$sql` variables. I edited my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should try

```
SELECT id, fullName, email, landLine, cellphone 
FROM members
WHERE id NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT member_id FROM orders)
LIMIT 50
```

Be sure to put indexes on `members.id` and `orders.member_id`.

Comment: a minute passed, it is still trying to load the page :( I got the same problem with other queries I tried. + 1 for DISTINCT idea. Thank you.

Comment: @Pixeler: I'm sorry it's taking so long time. Did you try to run separately queries? I mean: how long it takes to execute `SELECT DISTINCT member_id FROM orders`?

Answer (score 2):

a query will never work if you do `SELECT a,b FROM cLEFT JOIN d` without space. Otherwise query 1 should be fine and is in my opinion the better way to express it.

As for performance you should put indexes as Marco suggested. The optimizer should be smart enough to issue the same plan for all three queries.

Answer (score 1):

Alright here it is.  Remove the 'IS NULL' part at the end so you can see what is really going on; it's pretty simple when you see it =-)

**select * from members left join orders on members.id=orders.member_id WHERE member_id IS NULL;**

Note: I think you should change the name of your 'id' column to 'order_id' in the orders table and the 'id' column in the members table to 'member_id' to avoid a lot of confusion.  Also don't forget to add indexes.

I tested it using your table structure and my own values.  It returns Michael Jordan and Barack Obama because they did not have any orders.

```
INSERT INTO orders (id, member_id) VALUES ('aa', '1');
INSERT INTO orders (id, member_id) VALUES ('bb', '1');
INSERT INTO orders (id, member_id) VALUES ('cc', '1');
INSERT INTO orders (id, member_id) VALUES ('dd', '1');
INSERT INTO orders (id, member_id) VALUES ('gg', '2');
INSERT INTO orders (id, member_id) VALUES ('hh', '2');
INSERT INTO orders (id, member_id) VALUES ('ii', '2');
INSERT INTO orders (id, member_id) VALUES ('xx', '3');
INSERT INTO orders (id, member_id) VALUES ('yy', '3');
INSERT INTO orders (id, member_id) VALUES ('zz', '3');

INSERT INTO members (id, fullName, email, landLine, cellPhone) VALUES ('1', 'John smith', 'bigboy@yahoo.com', '1234567890', '1234567890');
INSERT INTO members (id, fullName, email, landLine, cellPhone) VALUES ('2', 'Person B', 'asfsdf@yahoo.com', '1234567890', '1234567890');
INSERT INTO members (id, fullName, email, landLine, cellPhone) VALUES ('3', 'Tom Brady', 'efe@yahoo.com', '1234567890', '1234567890');
INSERT INTO members (id, fullName, email, landLine, cellPhone) VALUES ('4', 'Michael Jordan', 'etett@yahoo.com', '1234567890', '1234567890');
INSERT INTO members (id, fullName, email, landLine, cellPhone) VALUES ('5', 'Barack Obama', 'sdfasf@yahoo.com', '1234567890', '1234567890');
```

Comment: Thanks, I am running the query on phpmyadmin; `select pre_members.id from pre_members left join pre_orders on pre_members.id=pre_orders.member_id WHERE member_id IS NULL;` a minute passed, phpmyadmin still trying to load...

Comment: PHPadmin is very very slow I'm using it right now as we speak for something else.  You just have to be patient.  I can guarantee you this works though and if you want to verify then test it in the MySQL workbench OR test it on a smaller subset of the data.  A trick I usually use with PHPAdmin is to add like a "show tables;" statement at the end of my queries so I know when PHPAdmin has finished running and I know it hasn't frozen.

Comment: I don't think it is normal to wait more than 12 minutes and still see at the right bottom of the browser Waiting for www.domain.com...

Comment: Either way it is taking a long time because it is probably doing something.  In PHP admin if there was an error it would stop and let you know.  Try it on certain members that start with like the letter "A" or something or even a specific name, to see if it ever finishes.

Comment: After playing around with JOIN I have more understanding right now. Thank you for your help Ray. I will accept Marco's answer. His query will be much faster. I already voted for your answer, thank you once again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First off make sure you have indexes on all of the columns you are using.

What you want to do is a left join on the member's ID and order's and whenever a member has a null value in the ID column they did not exist in the other table.  Test the query in the MySQL workbench first before you do it in PHP, so you can see what is happening.

If you show me your table structures I'll write out a working query for you.

Comment: Thank you, I also added the structure (I thought $sql variables would be enough the describe).

Comment: Check my other answer I posted a query that works.  I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st query seems to be ok.

Make sure:

1) that `orders.member_id` is an fk to `members.id`
2) there is an index on `orders.member_id` and `members.id`

I also suggest that you run your query directly on mysql client and optimize it there, then try from php. At least you will make sure, when optimized, that mysql is not the bottleneck, but something else.